# How to get  the path of the currently running batch job in MS-DOS?

Tags: java, windows, dos

I have a batch `foo.bar` in a directory `d:\progs\`.
In this directory I have a jar file called `bar.jar`.
I have added `d:\progs\` to my Path environment variable.

Now i do `cd c:\anotherdir`.
In this new dir i do `foo -v`. But i get the following error :
`Unable to access jarfile bar.jar`

How can i get the current path of `foo.bar` since %CD% returns `c:\anotherdir` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you're looking for is `%~dp0`. It gives you the [path of the currently running batch job](http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2005/01/28/get-directory-path-of-an-executing-batch-file.aspx).

This also has the advantage of allowing you to run the command from any location, whereas capturing `%CD%` in the beginning of your batch script will capture the directory that you were in when you started the batch script. (If this is what you *want* to do, however, that would be the preferred solution, as suggested by [Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581264/how-to-get-batch-current-directory-in-ms-dos/6581300#6581300).)

Comment: %dp~0 was the snippet I was looking for. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have added d:\progs\ to my Path environment variable.

That only affects launching programs, it doesn't help with arguments (eg. data files and documents) passed to the program.

> How can i get the current path of foo.bar since %CD% returns c:\anotherdir ?

Use `%CD%` to capture the current folder, and thus build the data file's path *before* changing directory.